# How to calculate how much size do I need in order to properly make MBR

Tags: assembly, mbr

I know that in the end of Master Boot Record (MBR) there is a magic number that tells BIOS it is the bootloader, And that we need to fill in the amount of bytes left until it is 512 bytes (MBR size), but how can do we calculate the amount of bytes that remain?

```
[bits 16] ; 16 bits assembly
[org 0x7c00]

start:
    ;; Call VideoService interrupt 0x10
    ;; ah = 0x00 -> SetVideoMode
    ;; al = 0x13 -> 320x200 16 color
    mov ah, 0x00
    mov al, 0x13
    int 0x10

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0 ; instead of 510, what number do I need to use?
dw 0xaa55 ; magic number tells BIOS it is the bootloader
```

**Instead of 510, what number do I need to use?**

Comment: You always need 510. That's 512 - 2 (the signature) and the `$-$$` take care of the rest.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Oh, so I can write whatever without need to change `times`?

Comment: As long as the expression `510 - ($ - $$)` is non-negative, yes. This will happen when your code size (which is given by `$ - $$`) becomes bigger than 510 bytes. The assembler will complain, so you'll know if that happens. Also, technically speaking `$-$$` works as long as you have a single section of code for the first stage of the bootloader, but that's almost always the case (if not always).

Comment: Do you understand how that `times` works? `$` is the current address, `$$` is the start of the section. So `$-$$` gives you how many bytes you have used so far. `510-($-$$)` thus gives you how many are left to 510 and that amount of zeroes are added. The `dw 0xaa55` then provides the signature in the final two bytes, bringing up the total to 512 to fill your sector.

Answer (score -2):

We always need 510. That's 512 - 2 (the signature) and the $-$$ takes care of the rest

### Can we write whatever we want without needing to change `times`?

As long as the expression 510 - ($ - $$) is non-negative, yes. This will happen when the code size (which is given by $ - $$) becomes bigger than 510 bytes. The assembler will complain, so you'll know if that happens. Also, technically speaking $-$$ works as long as you have a single section of code for the first stage of the bootloader, but that's almost always the case (if not always).  ([Margaret Bloom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5801661/margaret-bloom))

### How does `times` work?

`$` is the current address, `$$` is the start of the section. So `$-$$` gives how many bytes you have used so far. `510-($-$$)` thus gives you how many are left to 510 and that amount of zeroes are added. The `dw 0xaa55`  then provides the signature in the final two bytes, bringing up the total to 512 to fill your sector.  ([Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester))

Comment: stackoverflow uses CC BY-SA licensing. If you copy other people's content, you should attribute it to them. Also if you do not add any significant new information yourself, consider marking the answer as community wiki.

Comment: @Jester At first I tagged Margaret Bloom but then I thought that I should not. How can I mark the answer as community WIKI?

Comment: @Jester Where is the  checkbox under the edit area to the right?